# Swift - Parse JSON using Alamofire from PHP data

Tags: php, ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am trying to create an adapter using PHP for Chinese user to connect GoogleAPI. In the json response, I am trying to get the description data. But, I even can't get the dictionary data. Any suggestions?

iOS code

```
Alamofire.request(requestString, method: .post, parameters: data, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: [:]).responseJSON { (response) in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(_):
        print(response.result.value)
        if let dictionary = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,Any>{
            print("dictionary", dictionary)
        }
    }
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
$post_data = $_POST['data'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=KKEEYY");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-length: ".strlen($post_data)));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

**EDIT**

I can see there are extra "" for key and value if I use my own adapter

Response if Direct request to Google `print("direct", response.result.value)`

[image]

Response if using my adapter `print("using adapter", response.result.value)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your result is already a Dictionary no need to cast it with NSDictionary. Also, You have to use the swift classes avoid Objective-c classes in Swift:

**Try with this:**

```
switch response.result {
       case .success:
         if let jsonDict = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
            print("Json Response: \(jsonDict)") // serialized json response
             if let responses = jsonDict["responses"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                print("3", responses)
             }
         }
         if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Server Response: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
         }
         break
       case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            break
         }
}
```

Comment: the variable of resultDict?

Comment: Check it again.

Comment: result - Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: Updated check it out.

Comment: print("1", result) does not print anything

Comment: Because You are using all objective-c classes

Comment: Hi. I think you miss the key of "result" in the first one. And for the second one, json does not have a method of object. I also try json["result"] but still does not work.

Comment: I slightly change my PHP code by just ```echo json_encode($result); ``` in order to match your answer.

Comment: First one no need to result.

Comment: why no need to include "result" as key?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help..

```
let jsonData = response.data
let dictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: []) as? [String : Any]
print("dictionary", dictionary)
```

Comment: My attempt is close to you. Trying ```if let dictionary = response.result.value as? String {
                    let data: NSData = dictionary.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSData
                    let json = JSON(data)
                    print("JSON", json)
                    print("JSON1", json["responses"])``` I can see JSON1 is not nil

Answer (score -1):

to make it easier, it's better if you using swifty JSON and combine it with alamofire

Comment: Would you mind to see my edit? I found a difference between using my own adapter and requesting directly to Google

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer. I know it is so messy.

```
if let dictionary = response.result.value as? String {
    let data: NSData = dictionary.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSData
    let json = JSON(data)
    let responses = json["responses"].arrayObject
    if let resp = responses!.first {
        let type = resp as! [String: Any]
        if let labelAnnotations = type["labelAnnotations"] as? NSArray {
            for labelAnnotation in labelAnnotations {
                if let results = labelAnnotation as? NSDictionary {
                    let description = results["description"] as? String
                    let score = results["score"] as? Double
            }
        }
    }
}
```